# Fast shared disk in a Azure VM Scale set cluster

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-vm-scale-set

we are using Azure VM Scale sets to compute a larger job. In some stages we want the machines to share data with each other. We have tried Blob Storage for this but it's way to slow.

We are looking at either make the computers talking to each other or a simpler solution having them share a network drive (a fast one, being close to the actual hardware). Is this available in Azure? How we have understood it Azure Files is as slow as Blob storage because it's on top of blob storage.

Is it possible to create a disk that is shared between VM's in an Azure Scale Set?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. you might use network shares.

well, you can implement Software Defined Storage cluster, but thats probably overkill

Comment: What kind of networks shares are they that are fast?

Comment: Ok, but if not Azure Files what options are there for fast smb network shares?

Comment: just create a share on the vm thats accessible from all of those

Comment: Is there any information anywhere which I could use? I have started to look into lustre could that be something?